# LaTeX-Vim Return to edit after error?

Tags: vim, vim-latex

For example I compiled something, and got error, it gives me 3 splited windows in vim, but if I :q all of them, I quited the vim.

Is there a way so that I can go back to edit after compile error?

Comment: This is a question about Vim rather than about Latex, so you might not get much help here.  To close any split-window in Vim, move the cursor into that window so it has the focus and use `ZZ` or `:q`.  I guess you might be moving the focus back to your main file window?  Personally I get along fine without ever using split windows in Vim. I find vim-latex much too complicated.

Comment: Yeah it is complicated, when you got error, the vim-latex will pop-up 3 windows and seems shut the original window as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible command for going back to the previously edited file is:

> Ctrl+^

and another option is:

> :e#

Comment: Some things have to reach a certain level of pain before they seep into the consciousness so that I can google the problem - here it was quite a level. Thank you! 